# How do I add a section title in Elementor?

Tags: wordpress, web, elementor, developer-tools

I want to add a section titel on my elementor Website but I don't know to how!

are there any way to make it easily to my elementor website

Answer (score 0):

Use Heading widget from Elementor widget collection?